# cx_Oracle output different from Oracle SQL developer output for the same SQL query

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am facing a cx_Oracle/Oracle developer issue.

The Python/Oracle connection has been set up using cx_Oracle.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
db=cx_Oracle.connect('username/passwordZ@hostname:port/SID')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("My SQL Query Here")
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Then I got a data frame with 97 rows. But if I copy the same SQL Query to Oracle developer and run it, I got a output with much less rows. The SQL query is basically selecting all deals made before sysdate.

```
select table1.a, table2.b, table3.date
from table1, table2 , table2  
where table1.id = table2.id
and table1.id = table3.id 
and table2.Action = 'Y'
and table3.Date < 'sysdate'-1
```

I am guessing this issue is related to the 'sysdate' in the SQL query, the 'sysdate' can't be processed correctly to Oracle SQL which lead to different outputs.

Any one had some issue before and any suggestions?

Thank you!!!

Comment: are you using the actual sysdate function in Oracle?  (and table3.date < sysdate - 1).  you have single quotes around sysdate in your example which would be incorrect

Comment: `'sysdate'` is a string and in that context should return an error.

Comment: Might be a typo...but from table1, table2 , table2    is listing table 2 twice...might be getting odd results there.   As gordon points out, sysdate shouldn't be quoted, just sysdate - 1